# Specification for the type in a class using templates (instead of inheritance)

Tags: c++, templates

When inheriting from a class, you know the requirements and restrictions imposed on you by simply looking up the hierarchy. For example, you can find out just by looking at the parent class(es) which methods are required to be defined (pure virtual). If one chooses to use templates instead (if it fits the bill) then things are not as clear. The methods of the template class may be expecting several methods for the `type` to be present.

I ran across a complex class that I have to use. I did not know what methods my `type` (class/object) was supposed to have. The only way I could find out was by compiling where the compiler would let me know which methods were expected. It's like inheriting from an abstract class without access to the header file. This is a bit of a pain as it is time consuming to figure out the method specifications (signature).

Now the original designer of the class could have put some documentation as to which methods are expected to be present and their signatures, but I can't help but wonder if there is a way the code can be self documented (or is already and I don't know how to *view* it?). Compiling and looking at the errors can't be the only way, can it?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way around this, it's either documentation or compiler errors - pick your poison..

Comment: You could make a separate testing TU in which you only include the template, your scaffold class `Foo`, and an explicit instantiation `template class MasterClass<Foo>;`. That'll make the compiler instantiate all methods, and hopefully you can use the diagnostics to figure out what you need. Redesigning the template to include trait checking would be preferable if that's an option, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're essentially describing the kind of problem that [C++0x concepts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_(C%2B%2B)) was going to solve by providing programmers a way to enforce requirements on `type` at compile time. However, it was removed in July 2009 due to time constraints.

There is a library-only solution in Boost called the [Concept Check Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm) (BCCL). However, [there are differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352571/whats-the-difference-between-c0x-concepts-and-the-boost-concept-check-library) between the BCCL and what C++0x concepts was going to be. It's the closest thing to concepts we have for the current language.

If you much rather not have to use the BCCL, then documentation is the next best thing.

Answer (score 1):

There was a proposal for [concepts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_%28C%2B%2B%29) in C++11 that would have addressed this issue: a concept is essentially a description of an interface that a template parameter must fulfill. You can get similar functionality from the [Boost Concept Check Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm) if you need it now, but a class must be designed to make use of concept assertions from the beginning, so you're out of luck if you have an existing library.

Answer (score 1):

C++11 has added static_assert (which can be emulated in C++03 by BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT). Now you could write a lot of such asserts that will trigger at compile time, and add human readable documentation to it on why that assert triggered. Depending on what facilities you have to test (i.e. C++11 type_traits or only boost.type_traits) you can do more or less with it (also consider using decltype to check for the possibility of doing certain things, maybe combined with the sizeof trick, hard to tell in generic)

Answer (score 0):

Using composition and pure virtual classes avoids this problem.  Using and understanding the interfaces is easier.  Understanding how the implementation fulfills the interface is easier.  Unit testing is easier.

```
struct B {
  virtual ~B() {}
  virtual void foo() const = 0;
  virtual void bar() const = 0;
};

struct D : public B {
  virtual ~D() {}
  virtual void foo() const {foo_thing.call();}
  virtual void bar() const {bar_thing.call();}
private:
  some_foo_like_thing foo_thing;
  some_bar_like_thing bar_thing;
};
```

I would hope talking about what should and shouldn't be in a pure virtual interface should be easier, though mileage may vary.  ;)

The more information it takes to appreciate something, the harder it is to reason about it.  If your class relies on the implementation of its parent, then you essentially have to understand it and every one of its predecessors.  Not just the interface, but the implementation too.

If I were going to design a language, implementation inheritance wouldn't even be an option.